# iPad portrait viewport issue

Tags: ipad, media-queries

My test site is here: [one-story-beta.herokuapp.com](http://one-story-beta.herokuapp.com)

I am having an issue with the viewport in portrait mode, where the content is not scaling down correctly. It is fine in landscape view. This was my original viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

And then I tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

But neither seemed to fix the problem. I've also tried to set a media query for portrait mode, where I set the body to be 768px. Something like this:

```
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    body {
        max-width: 768px;
    }
    header {
        max-width: 768px;
    }

}
```

But that didnt work either.

Am i missing something obvious here?

Comment: This may seem like a silly question for your problem, but as I can find nothing wrong with your code, have you tried clearing your cache?